# Is there a self pointer to own class?

Tags: javascript, class

Is there some kind of "self" pointer to its own class in JavaScript ?

For example this code has a class called "banana".
I always want Objects of Class "Banana" to be added into the variable "BananaInstances", to never loose the pointer of the new object.
so i got to create a function called "CreateBanana()" which pushs every new object of class "Banana" into the BananaInstances-variable.

```
var BananaInstances = []

class Banana{
    constructor() {
        size = "huge"
    }
}


CreateBanana()
{
    SweetBanana = new Banana()
    BananaInstances.push(SweetBanana)
}

CreateBanana()
```

is there a way to avoid a "CreateBanana"-function and let the constructor of Class "Banana" push itself into "BananaInstances" ?

Comment: `BananaInstances.push(this)`. Inside the construsctor `this` refers to the newly created object.

Comment: With that said, it's usually very strange to have to keep track of all instances in the class itself. Usually that's the job of [an object pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within a class, the `this` keyword is the reference to *self*.

To keep the references of the **created instances** of a class - directly within a class use the `static` keyword.

> [<sup>MDN</sup> **Classes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) The `static` **keyword** defines a static method for a class. **Static methods** are **called without instantiating their class and cannot be called through a class instance**. Static methods are often used to create utility functions for an application.

```js
class Banana {

  static instances = [];
  size = "huge"
  
  constructor(props) {
    Object.assign(this, props);
    Banana.instances.push(this);
  }
}

const b1 = new Banana();
const b2 = new Banana({size: "normal"});

console.log(Banana.instances);  
// [Banana{"size": "huge"}, Banana{"size": "normal"}]
```

Instead of an Array we could also use **[new Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)**

> The [Set Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) lets you store **unique** values of any type, whether primitive values or **object references**.

Use `static instances = new Set;`
and than in the constructor use `Banana.instances.add(this);`

Notice that the above does not provide an out-of-the-box way to track garbage collected, deleted instances. If the necessity or a [Finalizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finalizer) arises, to remove it from the Set, a new class method like `destructor() { Banana.instances.delete(this); }` might be required.

```js
class Banana {

  static instances = new Set();
  size = "huge"
  
  constructor(props) {
    Object.assign(this, props);
    Banana.instances.add(this);
  }
  
  destructor() {
    Banana.instances.delete(this);
  }
}

const b1 = new Banana();
const b2 = new Banana({size: "normal"});

console.log([...Banana.instances]);  
// [Banana{"size": "huge"}, Banana{"size": "normal"}]

b1.destructor(); // Call destructor on b1
console.log([...Banana.instances]);  
// [Banana{"size": "normal"}]
```